# How Does the System Select the Appropriate Font Weight Using kCTFontWeightTrait?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, core-text

When specifying font weights with `kCTFontWeightTrait` in Core Text (iOS), how does the system choose the correct font weight, especially for weights not explicitly available in a font family (e.g., Thin, UltraLight, UltraBlack)?

- **Selection Process:** How is the font variant determined for weights that fall between available font family weights?
- **Missing Weights:** For weights absent in the font family, does the system simulate the weight (e.g., "fake" bold/thin), or does it default to the nearest available weight?
- **Best Practices:** Any recommended practices for ensuring accurate representation of desired font weights with kCTFontWeightTrait, especially in custom fonts?

Insights into how `kCTFontWeightTrait` impacts font rendering and selection would be very helpful.

Comment: Apple's docs state the `kCTFontWeightTrait` is *"a float value between -1.0 and 1.0"* ... Try experimenting with it?